HTML favicon not displayed
I am trying to add a favicon to my web page. However, the icon does not seem to be displayed properly by my browser. My code looks as follows:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title>Never pay too much for software licenses</title>

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href="assets/img/favicon.heic" rel="icon">
  <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.heic" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- Template Main CSS File -->
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

This screenshot shows the page in my browser with the default globe icon.

Is it really an heic image that is send from the server? Because that image format is essentially only supported in safari. And I actually don’t know if it is supported there as favicon.

The problem you are having with the favicon not displaying correctly in your browser is probably because .heic is an unsupported format for favicons. Most browsers support more common formats such as  .png, .jpg and svg. Support for favicons.

Favicons do not support the High Efficiency Image File Format (HEIC). Convert your icon to a supported file format, such as JPEG or PNG. Don't forget to change the extension in the href attribute accordingly.

You cannot use HEIC as a Favicon, Convert your icon using something like: favicon-converter which will give you all of the following formats in 1 shot:
android-chrome-192x192.png,
android-chrome-512x512.png,
apple-touch-icon.png,
favicon-16x16.png,
favicon-32x32.png,
favicon.ico,
site.webmanifest
and the code to copy to implement.
